# Submitting jobs with numeric arguments to QSUB using Python

Tags: python, subprocess, cluster-computing, pbs, qsub

I want to run a python function,say `my_fun(x1,x2)`, on different nodes of cluster with SGE (QSUB). I created a script `my_script.py` which takes in the numeric arguments from the command line, so when running locally, I'd call it as

```
python my_script.py x1 x2
```

Now I want to submit this script to the cluster in a loop with different values of x1 and x2. Also, for the node to have access to python & the installed modules, I need to run `module load Python/2.7` on the node before calling the python script through QSUB.

This seems like a pretty simple and typical use-case, but I can't find any straightforward way to do this from Python. Going back and forth between BASH and Python seems a bit clunky.

Comment: please, have a look at array jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This more or less does what I'm looking for:

https://gist.github.com/timflutre/a9085660271bd059f71c

```
import sys
import subprocess

job_param1 = 12.5
job_param2 = 5.0
jobName = "python my_script.py %f %f" % (job_param1,job_param2)
cmd = "module load Python/2.7; sleep 0.2; %s" % jobName
echoArgs = ["echo", "-e", "'%s'" % cmd]
print(" ".join(echoArgs))
qsubArgs = ["qsub","-cwd"]
print(" ".join(qsubArgs))

wholeCmd = " ".join(echoArgs) + " | " + " ".join(qsubArgs)
out = subprocess.Popen(wholeCmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = out.communicate()[0]

jobId = out.split()[2]
print jobId
```

Comment: Of course, I'll be running the body inside a (python) FOR loop.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you divide the job into multiple independent jobs depending on the number of nodes you have.

For each node/core, create a folder with a file containing the a list of the parameters this subjob should treat. Then in python, write a script which reads the file and calls your script (maybe using the multiprocessing module for multi-core support).

EDIT:

If you want to pass additional parameters through qsub, you can call qsub with arguments which can be passed to your script:

```
qsub -F "myarg1 myarg2 myarg3=myarg3value" myscript.sh
```

You can find this documentation [here](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/suite/8-0/basic/help.htm#topics/torque/commands/qsub.htm)

Comment: That's horribly inefficient for the number of jobs I need to submit. I think there are ways to do this without requiring writing files to disk.

Comment: where do your x1 x2 values come from? because qsub is also inefficient for calling small scripts

Comment: Another suggestion if you are looking for a way to farm out your jobs would be to use ipython/jupyter which allows you to start up a bunch of workers, submit calculations and collect the results.

Comment: That would have been my preferred way actually, but unfortunately, the ipengines kept crashing on importing one module (sklearn.svm). Doing the import through QSUB seems to be fine. I have no idea why. Here's my post on that issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531089/ipython-parallel-on-sge-cluster-scikit-learn-svc-parallel-import-causes-engine

Comment: That is weird. Sorry I can't help you there.